# Finding the coefficients of the series solution of an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I shell present 2 questions I came across today related to this subject.
I need some explanation about the meaning of the IVP I am given.

We look for a solution of the form $y=\sum a_nx^n$.

So after doing the algebra using these 2: 
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n(x-x_0)^{n-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_n(x-x_0)^{n-2}$$ 
I came up with the following recurrence relations:

1. (a) $(x^2-2)y''+6xy'+4y=0$. The recurrence relation to this eq. is $$a_{n+2}=a_n\cdot \frac{n+4}{2(n+2)}$$
   The Initial values are
   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   y'(0)=0\\ 
   y(0)=1
   \end{matrix}\right.$$
   And my textbook states that this leads to$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   a_0=1\\ 
   a_1=0
   \end{matrix}\right.$$.
2. (b) $(1+x^2)y''+3xy'+y=0$. The recurrence relation to this eq. is $$a_{n+2}=-a_n\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$
   The Initial values are
   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   y'(0)=1\\ 
   y(0)=2
   \end{matrix}\right.$$
   And my textbook states that this leads to$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   a_0=2\\ 
   a_1=1
   \end{matrix}\right.$$.
3. (c) $(1+x^2)y''-6y=0$. The recurrence relation to this eq. is $$a_{n+2}=-a_n\cdot \frac{n-3}{n+1}$$
   The Initial values are
   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   y'(0)=0\\ 
   y(0)=1
   \end{matrix}\right.$$
   And my textbook states that this leads to$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
   a_0=1\\ 
   a_1=0
   \end{matrix}\right.$$.

I simply have no idea how to determine the correct $a_0$ and the correct $a_1$. Who goes to the $y'$ and who goes the $y$?

Answer (score 1):

As Amzoti noted in a comment, $a_0$ is the value of the function at the point of expansion, and $a_1$ is the value of its derivative there. Both facts follows from the  [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) formula.

Note that  $a_0$ and $a_1$ are determined from initial conditions only. From the ODE you get the recurrence relation. Together they determine the rest of coefficients.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me "answer my self": We assume a solution in form $y=a_0 +a_1 x+a_2 x^2 +\ldots$, so that if I am told that $y(0)=k\in\mathbb{R}$ then $y(0)=a_0 +a_1\cdot 0 +\ldots$ or simply $a_0=k$. The same with the 1st derivative: $y'(0)=a_1 +2 a_2 x+\ldots$. Correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.